# Extract ArrayList values from Adapter to GridView

Tags: java, android

I can find plenty of examples of how to use ArrayList in the BaseAdapter class to fill a GridView, but I am having difficulty
passing the correct values. This was working fine  while I was just using the cursor positions, but I need to use an
ArrayList now. As far as I know the solution lies in correctly populating the getItem and getItemID. Where is the mistake - 
can somebody help please? Relevant code below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

allImages = Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
ArrayList<String> imageCollection = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] projection = {
      MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
      MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
};
getCursor = getContentResolver().query(
      allImages,
      projection,
      null,
      null,
      null
);
columnIndex = getCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);  //-- ID number.
arrayIndex  = getCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[1]);  //-- Filepath.
imageCollection.add(String.valueOf(columnIndex));

GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, imageCollection));
}  //---End of OnCreate --

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int colCount;
    private ArrayList<String> tempCollection;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> anyCollection) {
        context = c;
        tempCollection = anyCollection;
        colCount = tempCollection.size();
    }
    //---Returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return colCount;
    }
    //---Returns the item---
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return tempCollection.get(position);

    }
    //---Returns the ID of one item. 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    } 

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  //---If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes --
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    String imageID  = String.valueOf(position);  //--- FAILS: always 0, causing FileNotFound Exception below.!!!
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    imageView.setCropToPadding(true);
    imageView.setImageURI(                //--- Now create each individual display image --
        Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageID)
    );
    return imageView;
} //---End of ImageAdapter class--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In activity, use below code for saving the ImageId to the ArrayList.

```
if (getCursor != null) {
    while (getCursor.moveToNext()) {
      columnIndex = getCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);  
      imageCollection.add(String.valueOf(getCursor.getLong(columnIndex));
    }
 }
```

In ImageAdapter, getView method, get the ImageId by using below code:

```
String imageID  = tempCollection.get(position);
```

Comment: In the original post I assumed the ArrayList was fully populated _before_ trying to extract the imageID; and am still not clear on this, so is it correct that there are no cursor.moveToPosition commmands in the GetView class. Sorry about this, but can find no documentation anywhere. The code above looks promising so will try now.