# GridView BaseAdapter notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android, arraylist

Having successfully added the ability to load images from an `ArrayList`, then I am unable to refresh the display when a new `ArrayList` arrives. It appears that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not working correctly. I have seen many problems with this, all different, whilst looking for a solution but nothing appears to work here. Relevant code below:

```
final ImageAdapter myAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,imageCollection); //---Initial onCreate call--
....
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this,newTemp);
adapter.updateContent(newTemp);                                 //---Need to refresh display here--
....
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final int colCount;
    private ArrayList<String> anyCollection;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> anyCollection) {
        super();
        this.context = c;
        this.anyCollection = anyCollection;
        this.colCount = anyCollection.size();               //--- 16 and then 3 (ArrayList sizes)--
        Log.d("DEBUG","Line 124 Size: " + this.colCount);   //--- Shows ArrayList size (Correct) --
    }

    public void updateContent (ArrayList<String> updates) {
        Log.d("DEBUG","Line 126 " + this.anyCollection.size());              //--- Shows 3 again --
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();                  //--- Screen still shows original 16 images--
    }

    //---Returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return colCount;
    }
    ....
```

Comment: you have declared your `colCount` as final. Thus if you add more items, the count will be the same. Try again without the `final` keyword.

Comment: Also, if `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't work, try calling `adapter.clear()` and `adapter.addAll(yourCollection)` when you want to update the `ListView`

Comment: I forgot to override getCount method so when i override, the problem is solved for me. hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `updates` to your collection:

```
public void updateContent(ArrayList<String> updates) {
    anyCollaction.addAll(updates);
    Log.d("DEBUG","Line 126 " + this.anyCollection.size());              //--- Shows 3 again --
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();                  //--- Screen still shows original 16 images--
}
```

In addition, you should update `colCount` when you add new values.

You should not create new `ImageAdapter` instances everytime you want to update content:

```
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, newTemp);
adapter.updateContent(newTemp);
```

Comment: I tried this but as I saw the 3 ArrayList values (in LogCat) were already there, ie not 0, I removed it.

Comment: I tried this but as I saw the 3 ArrayList values (in LogCat) were already there, ie not 0, I removed it.

Comment: Can you send the whole source code since I don't know what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: Original source code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364794/extract-arraylist-values-from-adapter-to-gridview (Before some minor errors fixed) .All I am trying to do is replace the 16 thumbnails displayed initially in GridView with 3 new ones received from another Intent. Regarding the final _colCount_, I am getting the new correct values each time (see LogCat comments).

Comment: After receiving Intent do you want to have 3 or 19 thumbnails in grid?

Comment: Is this problem implying that I must be passing in an array of _Bitmaps_? At present I am passing in an array of _references_
to the SDcard and extracting the filepath using Cursor movement. A large bitmap array is going to cause an OutOfMemory exception.
Or could it be a _Context_ issue?

Comment: No, passing image url or path is fine.

Comment: Solved: I had 2 lines missing from the updateContent method, as mentioned above. Now I just have to access the correct new images.